# Zeros of an entire function on the boundary of a rectangle

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and not identically zero. Consider a rectangle $R_\epsilon=\{s=\sigma+it\in\mathbb{C}\mid \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}+\epsilon,\ 0\leq y\leq \frac{3}{2}+\epsilon\}$ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrarily small
and given that $f(z)$ is non zero on $\mathbb{R}$ i.e. the real axis.

**Question:** Prove that we can choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(z)$ has no zeros on the boundary of rectangle $R_\epsilon$.

My try: Let $\partial{R_\epsilon}$ be the boundary of the rectangle $R_\epsilon$. Let $C_\epsilon$ be $\partial{R_\epsilon}\setminus \mathbb{R}$. Suppose on the contrary such an $\epsilon$ does not exist. Then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $z$ on $\partial{R_\epsilon}$. But $f(z)$ is non zero on $\mathbb{R}$, so $z\in C_\epsilon$.

Then I want to use the fact that the zeros of an analytic function are isolated. I am struggling to prove the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let us show that there are no zeros on the boundary whenever $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.

Suppose $\epsilon_n \to 0$ and $f(z_n)=0$ for some $z_n \in \partial R_{\epsilon_n}$.  If $\{z_n: n\geq 1\}$ is an infinite set, then, since it is also bounded, it has  convergent subsequnce. In this case the zeros of $f$ have a limit point and $f \equiv 0$, a contradiction. It follows that $(z_n)$ is constant along  a subsequence. But the boundaries of the rectangles have only a segment of the real axis in common. It follows that for some $n$,  $z_n$  lies on the real axis, again a contardiction.

Comment: Thank you. How is $\{z_n: n\geq 1\}$ a bounded set?

Comment: All your rectangles are contained  in $[0,2]\times [0,3]$ as long as $0<\epsilon <1$. @Ken

Comment: Thank you. How is $(z_n)$ constant along  a subsequence?

Comment: What are $\epsilon_n$'s? You did not define them anywhere

Comment: I am proving that there are no zeros on the boundaries of the rectangles for sufficiently small $\epsilon$. If you assume  the contrary then there exists a sequence $\epsilon_n$ tending to $0$ such that $f$ has  zero on the boundary of $R_{\epsilon_n}$ for every $n$. From this I have arrived at a contradiction.  @Ken

Comment: I am sorry. I could not follow your last comment. We have to prove that we can choose $\epsilon>0$ such that there are no zeros on the boundary of rectangle $R_\epsilon$. How does your method help here?

Comment: If that is what you want to prove then you can just take $\epsilon_n=\frac 1 n$ in my argument. What I have proved is a stronger statement that there are no zeros on the boundary whenever $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small.  @Ken

Comment: Thank you again. So you have proved that there are no zeros on the boundary when $\epsilon$ is "sufficiently small". What do you mean by sufficiently small?

Comment: It means that there exist $\epsilon_0>0$ such that there are no zeros on $\partial R_{\epsilon}$ whenever $0 <\epsilon <\epsilon_0$. @Ken

Comment: Thank you. How did you say that "it follows that $(z_n)$ is constant along  a subsequence"?